# Prefetching responses from web services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have an Index action method that loads two view models which eventually calls 2 AJAX action methods. These two AJAX action methods depend on the response of a webservice calls. so only one call to this webservice is needed to fulfill the 2 ajax action method's dependency. The problem is that this webservice is quite slow and takes several seconds to complete a request. I would  like 1) to call the webservice once for both of these action methods. 2) prefetch the response by making an async call to the webservice call at the execution of the Index action method. The hope is to make the UI load faster.

My worry is how do I delay the rendering of the 2 AJAX calls until the response from the async webservice call has completed?

Comment: Could you show some skeleton code to better illustrate your current implementation? I don't quite understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your situation.  Can you tie the async call to a partial view loaded by the main view and have Javascript in the partial view that would kick off the AJAX calls?